# Install pysqlcipher on Ubuntu - ImportError

Tags: python, encryption, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04, sqlcipher

From python 2.7, I'm developing a program which requires the encryption a database. In this way, I wish to install on my PC, with Ubuntu, the fork of pysqlite I mean pysqlcipher. I'm following this [tutorial](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/encrypted-sqlite-databases-with-python-and-sqlcipher/) but when I enter this code in my terminal:

```
python setup.py build_sqlcipher
```

I get this Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 38, in <module>
    import setuptools
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I don't understand because I have already installed setuptools.

Thank you for everyone helping me!

Comment: Are you running Python in a virtual environment? Also, check the version of Python you are executing (`python --version`), and make sure you have setuptools installed for that version.

Comment: @HermanSchaaf:  Thanks for your help, but finally I had used the solution I have posted.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

To succed the installation of **sqlcipher on Ubuntu 14.04LTS**, you have to use **Python 2.7**. Then, I have followed these steps below entered into the terminal:

1. sudo apt-get install sqlite3
2. sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
3. git clone https://github.com/leapcode/pysqlcipher/
4. cd pysqlcipher
5. python setup.py build_sqlcipher  # Build against the system libsqlcipher

You may encounter an error message like: */usr/bin/ld: cannot find...*

One solution I have used to skip this issue is to run:

1. sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
2. automake autotools-dev g++ g++-4.8 libbison-dev libc6-dev libsigsegv2 libssl-doc libstdc++-4.8-dev linux-libc-dev m4
3. autoconf automake autotools-dev bison build-essential g++ g++-4.8 libbison-dev libc6-dev libsigsegv2 libssl-dev libssl-doc libstdc++-4.8-dev linux-libc-dev m4 zlib1g-dev

Then to conclude the installation, enter this in the terminal:

- sudo python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

**Build against bundled libsqlcipher**

The default behaviour is to link against libsqlcipher in the system.

For convenience, this package includes a sqlcipher amalgamation during the regular install. See https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

If you don't have sqlcipher installed in the system, you can use the bundled pysqlcipher:

python setup.py install --bundled

You can also pass a different amalgamation path, that you have previously downloaded:

python setup.py install --bundled --amalgamation=/tmp/path/to/amalgamation

If you are installing from pip but for some reason you prefer to use the bundled sqlcipher, you should pass the option along:

**pip install pysqlcipher --install-option="--bundled"**